# Is there a type safe way to access store members in ngrx/store?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I've been going through the documentation for ngrx/store using angular2

https://github.com/ngrx/store

https://github.com/ngrx/example-app

The example app above implies i should access the observable members of the store using :

```
counter: Observable<number>;
constructor(private store: Store<AppState>){
    this.counter = store.select('counter');
}
```

Using a string of `'counter'` to access an object member feels antithetical to TypeScript. Is there a type safe way to access store members?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of [`select`](https://github.com/ngrx/core/blob/v1.2.0/src/operator/select.ts#L11-L26):

```ts
export function select<T, R>(pathOrMapFn: any, ...paths: string[]): Observable<R> {
  let mapped$: Observable<R>;
  if (typeof pathOrMapFn === 'string') {
    mapped$ = pluck.call(this, pathOrMapFn, ...paths);
  }
  else if (typeof pathOrMapFn === 'function') {
    mapped$ = map.call(this, pathOrMapFn);
  }
  else {
    throw new TypeError(`Unexpected type ${ typeof pathOrMapFn } in select operator,`
      + ` expected 'string' or 'function'`);
  }
  return distinctUntilChanged.call(mapped$);
}
```

You'll see that passing a string is equivalent to [`pluck`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-pluck), but passing a selector function is equivalent to [`map`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map) - which is type safe.

So pass a selector function. That's what's done in the [example app](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/containers/selected-book-page.ts#L26-L29).

Using your example:

```ts
counter: Observable<number>;
constructor(private store: Store<AppState>){
  this.counter = store.select(state => state.counter);
}
```

Comment: praise jebus / spider pig! i was very worried about introducing a bunch of magic strings into my project